# Apache storm can not find main class of storm starter

Tags: java, apache-storm

I am setting up an Apache Storm system but am having problems getting the program to run consistently.  I have set up storm on three servers but it only works consistently on one. I think the issue lies somewhere in the path of the command.

I have been using storm-starter to set up the program and have tested it locally with RollingTopWords.  When I run the following command `$ storm jar storm-starter-*.jar storm.starter.RollingTopWords` the computer stalls a second then i get the following error:

> Could not find or load main class storm.starter.RollingTopWords

The jar is stored in the directory /apache/storm/examples/storm-starter/target .  Let me know if there is any other information I can provide that would be of help because I'm feeling a little desperate at this point.

The following is the entire output for the program that doesn't work.

> Running: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -client -Dstorm.options= -Dstorm.home=/home/scix3/apache/storm -Dstorm.log.dir=/home/scix3/apache/storm/logs -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib -Dstorm.conf.file= -cp /home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/kryo-2.21.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/core.incubator-0.1.0.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/ring-servlet-0.3.11.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/clj-stacktrace-0.2.2.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/jline-2.11.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/disruptor-2.10.1.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/clojure-1.5.1.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/commons-exec-1.1.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/logback-core-1.0.13.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/carbonite-1.4.0.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/compojure-1.1.3.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/minlog-1.2.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/tools.macro-0.1.0.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/reflectasm-1.07-shaded.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/tools.cli-0.2.4.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/math.numeric-tower-0.0.1.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/logback-classic-1.0.13.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/tools.logging-0.2.3.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/asm-4.0.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/snakeyaml-1.11.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/hiccup-0.3.6.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/clj-time-0.4.1.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/jgrapht-core-0.9.0.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/clout-1.0.1.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/chill-java-0.3.5.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/joda-time-2.0.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/storm-core-0.9.4.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/objenesis-1.2.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/ring-core-1.1.5.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/ring-jetty-adapter-0.3.11.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/ring-devel-0.3.11.jar:storm-starter-*.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/conf:/home/scix3/apache/storm/bin -Dstorm.jar=storm-starter-*.jar storm.starter.RollingTopWords
>   Error: Could not find or load main class storm.starter.RollingTopWords

Comment: There are a lot of things that could be going wrong. First off, what do you mean by "I have set up storm on three servers"? Do you have a nimbus and two supervisors? Do you simply have three servers with storm installed?

Comment: Assuming you have run `maven package`, where are you running the "storm" command from?

Comment: I have storm the storm command set as part of JAVA_HOME so I have been running it from a number of places.  I have storm installed on three computers and am trying to have them all work locally before attaching them.  However, I have configured some of the yaml file so that they could connect.  Similarly, I have run the storm nimbus and storm supervisor on each of the systems.  Is it possible that the systems got confused because I run nimbus and supervisor on them?   Indeed, I have maven package.

Comment: What directory are you attempting to run the `storm` command from? Also, at this point, you don't need to be running the nimbus or supervisor processes, as these don't matter for simply running in local mode.

Comment: I've been running the storm command from many places.  The home, apache, storm, examples, and target directories for the most part.  On the system I have working I am able to run storm from anywhere on the computer since I put a path to it.

Comment: Something to note is that on both systems that currently are not working have worked in the past.  I am setting storm up by SSHing onto the servers and they both stopped working after logging off of the server and the back on. @rmlan

Comment: Just to confirm, you should be running `storm jar storm-starter-*-jar-with-dependencies.jar storm.starter.RollingTopWords` (note: the jar with all the dependencies) command to run it in local mode.. where the `*` should be replaced by the actual jar version name. is that correct ?

Comment: @user2720864 I've been running the command with the * rather than the actual version... I'm really new to computer science and wasn't aware that the * means "fill in with your version."  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 4):

The main issue  for the error
`Could not find or load main class storm.starter.RollingTopWords` cloud be.

1. Check the `launch configuration` while building the jar.
     you must be very careful while building the jar ,it asks you to choose destination folder and launch configuration(launch configuration should be of same project)
2. You might have missed the `main class` in your project.

Before using `Stormsubmitter` in Remote cluster, check once weather it works properly `localcluster`

Answer (score 1):

To check if the problem is with storm unable to find the jar, you can try issuing

```
storm jar /fullpath/my-storm-jar.jar Classname
```

Few other things you can make sure

1. The jar is compiled properly/jar contains the RollingTopWords class
2. storm.yaml points to the correct nimubs (This seems less probable, as the the connection is being made and there is an attempt to load the topology)